# [nodeJS][python-shell]How to send image using python-shell?(nodejs to python)

Tags: python, node.js

I'm working on a project and I need to send image(frame) in realtime.
Server is NodeJs, and I will process this image using OpenCV in python-shell
But I don't know how to send Image through python shell, to python code..
can you tell me how to send image from nodejs to python?

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');


var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions:['-u'],
    scriptPath:'C:/Users/multi/'
};


PythonShell.PythonShell.run("pycudacode.py",options,function(err){
    if(err) console.log('err msg:', err);
    console.log('finishied');
}
)
```

this is my code.
thank you.

Comment: The simplest mechanism would be to write the image to a temporary file and then send a message or command line parameter to your python program that contains the filename.  The python program can pick up the image from the file.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh thank you. I solved it  using send.

Answer (score 0):

```
global.pyshell = require('python-shell');
var fs = require("fs");


var data = fs.readFileSync("testimg.jpg"); // I will get video frame from the client.
var base64 = data.toString("base64");

var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions:['-u'],
    scriptPath:'C:/Users/multi/'
};



shell = new pyshell.PythonShell("sendex.py",options,function(err){
    if(err) console.log('err msg:', err);
    console.log('finishied');
}
)

shell.send(base64);

shell.on("message", rebase64 => {
    var err = null;
    result = Buffer.from(rebase64, "base64");
    console.log(result);
    console.timeEnd("time")
    fs.writeFileSync("result.jpeg",result);
});
shell.end(err=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I solved it and it is my code.

Comment: did you connect this to a frontend?